# How to change the color of bootstrap's pagination

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

So I am designing a site and I decided to use bootstrap's pagination to navigate between pages, since I am limited on time, really. any Idea how could I use something like "bg-dark", "bg-primary"...etc to change the color of my pagination? or even using plain css to change it (I would not mind really)

Comment: You mean change the color of pagination buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add class on all  from them:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/
and use style css with active element
example:

```css
.page-item.active .page-link {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #f00 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="bg-warning text-danger page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="bg-warning text-danger page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item bg-success  active">
      <a class="bg-warning text-danger page-link" href="#">2 <span class=" bg-success sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="bg-warning text-danger page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="bg-warning text-danger page-link" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using something like the [official example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/):

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you could add a css like this:

```
.pagination .page-link {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

This sets the color of any element with page-link class inside the element with pagination class